# Многопроцессный код(multiprocessing) python не работает как надо

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

У меня есть код:

```py
import multiprocessing as mpl
import stocker
from time import time
import threading


def fill_d(data):
    d, name, lock = data
    val = stocker.predict.tomorrow(name)  # val = [predicted price, error(%), date of the next business day]
    try:
        lock.acquire()
        data = d[name][val[-1]]
        data.append(val[0])
        d[name][val[-1]] = data
    except KeyError:
        d[name] = {}
        d[name][val[-1]] = [val[0]]
    finally:
        lock.release()


def runner(name, d, l):
    t = time()
    with mpl.Pool() as p:
        p.map(fill_d, [(d, name, l) for _ in range(5)])
    print(f'{round(time() - t, 2)}s')


stock = ['AAPL', 'AMZN']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mpl.Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    threads = []
    for name in stock:
        t = threading.Thread(target=runner, args=(name, d, manager.Lock()))
        threads.append(t)
        print(f'[+] Start thread {t.name}')
        t.start()
        '''Я думаю что каждый поток должен иметь свой lock, в противном случае потоки будут "ждать друг-друга"
        '''
    for i in threads:
        i.join()
    print(d)
```

Который должен выдавать такой результат:

```py
{'AAPL': {'2020-11-03': [109.56, 109.13, 109.48, 109.2, 108.44]}, 'AMZN': {'2020-11-03': [3014.6, 3003.31, 3009.34, 3011.31, 2994.48]}}
```

А я получаю такой результат:

```py
{'AAPL': {}, 'AMZN': {}}
```

Я убрал из кода multiprocessing и threading, и всё заработало.

```py
import stocker

d, name = {}, 'AAPL'


def fill(n):
    global d, name
    for i in range(n):
        val = stocker.predict.tomorrow(name)  # val = [predicted price, error(%), date of the next business day]
        try:
            data = d[name][val[-1]]
            data.append(val[0])
            d[name][val[-1]] = data
        except KeyError:
            d[name] = {}
            d[name][val[-1]] = [val[0]]


fill(5)
name = 'AMZN'
fill(5)

print(
    d)  # {'AAPL': {'2020-11-03': [109.56, 109.13, 109.48, 109.2, 108.44]}, 'AMZN': {'2020-11-03': [3014.6, 3003.31, 3009.34, 3011.31, 2994.48]}}
```

**Чего же я хочу?**
Я хочу чтобы два потока заполняли d некоторыми данными через multiprocessing. Или просто заставить первый код работать.
Спасибо.

Comment: `pip install stocker`

Comment: Кст, `global d, name` не нужны, т.к. вы не переприсваиваете те переменные

Comment: @gil9red, у меня stocker установлен.

Comment: @gil9red, моя цель - заставить первый код работать

Comment: А это не вам, а тем, кто захочет помочь, т.к. `stocker` не входит в стандартную библиотеку

Comment: Засунул `print('Error:', e)` в `except KeyError as e:` и наловил кучу ошибок (без `stocker` т.к. у меня еще `tensorflow` устанавливается, вместо кода с `stocker` засунул заглушку `val = [266.07, 1.276, '2019-11-11']`, ссылка с заглушкой https://pastebin.com/C4ezuX5h)

Comment: `Error: 'AAPL'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: 'AMZN'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: '2019-11-11'
Error: '2019-11-11'`

Comment: @gil9red, 'AMZN' err
{'AMZN': {}}
Главная проблема что когда мы  перехватываем первую ошибку(Error: 'APPL' или Error: 'AMZN') код в в except  не создаёт {'APPL': {'2019-11-11': [266.07]}}.

Comment: print(d) после кода в except выдаёт такой словарь {'AMZN': {}}, а должен такой. {'AMZN': {'2019-11-11': [266.07]}}

Comment: @gil9red, если решить эту проблему, то всё должно заработать. В моём примере except должен выполняться два раза

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте просто из функции для `map` возвращать значение, тогда они, значения, вернутся как список.

Пример:

```
import multiprocessing as mpl
import stocker
from time import time
import threading


def fill_d(data):
    name = data
    val = stocker.predict.tomorrow(name)  # val = [predicted price, error(%), date of the next business day]
    # val = [266.07, 1.276, '2019-11-11']
    return val


def runner(name, d):
    t = time()
    with mpl.Pool() as p:
        d[name] = p.map(fill_d, [[name] for _ in range(5)])
    print(f'{round(time() - t, 2)}s')


stock = ['AAPL', 'AMZN']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mpl.Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    threads = []
    for name in stock:
        t = threading.Thread(target=runner, args=(name, d))
        threads.append(t)
        print(f'[+] Start thread {t.name}')
        t.start()
        
    for i in threads:
        i.join()
    print(d)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пример понятен. На последок хочу спросить, есть ли у вас какие-то советы по улучшению производительности(например можно заменить threading на mlp.Process)?

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Неа, тут мне нечего добавить

Comment: мне прийдётся вас разочаровать.
Я чуть-чуть изменил ваш код:https://pastebin.com/xmEQCMip
Но в конце я получаю {'AAPL': {}, 'AMZN': {}}.
Хотя mlp.map возвращает валидный список. И я явно пишу: d[name][tomorrow] = sum(data) / len(data)

Comment: Выводы с моего кода.
{'AAPL': {}, 'AMZN': {}} [108.45, 108.43, 107.97, 107.17, 108.01]
2020-11-03 tomorrow
{'AAPL': {}, 'AMZN': {}} [2984.77, 3000.47, 2997.89, 2989.02, 2988.3]
2020-11-03 tomorrow
{'AAPL': {}, 'AMZN': {}}

Comment: проверьте ссылку и вы всё поймёте.

Comment: Пока галочку снимать не буду

Comment: Странноватый `manager.dict()`, добавил `print(d)` в конец функции `runner` и тот выводит `{'AAPL': {}, 'AMZN': {}}` хотя строкой выше `d[name][tomorrow] = sum(data) / len(data)`. Погуглил и нашел такой ответ https://stackoverflow.com/q/46049017/5909792, после поменял на присванивание `d[name] = {tomorrow: sum(data) / len(data)}` и получилось

Comment: спасибо большое. Теперь всё работает.

Comment: не работало потому что https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870270/2231972

Comment: @RomanKonoval, спасибо за инфу, действительно, тот словарь не мог контролировать изменение внутренних объектов, не привязанных к нему